# Confused with Marshmallow permission system

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I was understanding, before any action which involve a critical permission, I have to check if the permission was allowed by the user, and if it was not, show a rationale asking for the permission. And then I will be collecting the result in `onRequestPermissionsResult` callback method and so on.

But testing the app with a Nexus 6p I find out the platform automatically is showing a rationale before any of my method be called. Seems as just reading the manifest the platform is showing rationales to the user, So, I can't understand if is worth or not to check and create permissions method. Or if it is a new OS feature, which made out of date ask for permissions (my phone is running 6.0.1).

Here is the code which is managing permissions:

```
private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PermissionHelper.SMS_PERMISSION_IDENTIFIER);
        }
    }


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PermissionHelper.LOCATION_PERMISSION_IDENTIFIER: {
                if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Our app will be unable to locate you.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
            }
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
                break;
        }
    }
```

But my concern is not related with the code, but with the fact that the platform seems as is not needing this. Because when the app is just starting (but without reach yet any permission's code), just reading the AndroidManifest.xml, is immediately asking to the user to grant all the permissions. Making pointless all the permission code.

The Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- Internet access is required to show Google maps. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- To use Google places -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!-- These services require your GPS location. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- To detect if an internet connection is available. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- We would like to know your phone number. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<!-- To be reminded of insurance/MOT/servicing renewal then -->
<!-- we'll need to register those alarms on boot-up. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<!-- push notifications -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="ie.aaireland.android.theaa.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Here is an screenshot of the default rationale:

[image]

And this is the rationale showed when getActivity() is executed:

[image]

Comment: Please provide your code. It is hard to understand what you're doing from just text. I've written a diagram about the proper manner to use Marshmaloow here, see if you're following it: http://blog.safedk.com/technology/the-marshmallows-are-coming-new-permissions-model-is-almost-here/

Comment: Hi Ori Lentz, thanks for your help. I edit the post to show the code, in despite the code is not the point. The point is if the code is necessary or not, being the OS is asking to user for grant the permissions, without need to read any line of code related with permissions in the app.

Comment: @Im2a Yes, your code looks fine. So the question is: does this happen to you when you install the app or during runtime?

Comment: Hi Ori, this is happening when I install the app. Automatically I start to see a rationale asking the user for 4 permissions. Of course I am installing the app from a USB connection. First is showing "the default rationale" (the platform one). And immediately my own rationale (which is coming from my code)

Comment: @Im2a Okay, can you share you manifest as well? Also, looking over your code once again, I take back what I said about it being fine. I think the issue is something else, but still I don't see where you show your own rationale. You simply requestPermission once you see it's not granted. Am I misssing something?

Comment: Hi Ori, beyond the code, I want to know if asking permissions by default is an expected behaviour for Marshmallow. And if it is, so, which is the point to create our own code to ask for permissions?

Comment: It's not an expected behavior. That's why I'm asking to see your manifest. I think the answer my lay in there. However, since I'm not seeing the code where you present your own rationale, I might be wrong. Anyway, if you could edit and add the manifest, that would help me try to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104267/discussion-between-lm2a-and-ori-lentz).

Answer (score 1):

A summary of what was discussed privately in chat for anyone who finds this interesting later on:

- This portion of the application was done correctly, following the guidelines of the new [Runtime Permission model](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) in Android Marshmallow.
- The problem was that while the app started, four permission requests were given in bulk.
- The problem wasn't with the portion of code supplied, but stemmed from a self-written library (for internal use) which asked for all permissions when it was first called. This was done in order to make the library compatible quickly.
- **Solution**: Rewrite the library to ask for permissions when they are actually needed, so the entire app could have the Marshmallow-expected user behavior.

Good Luck :)

Comment: Many thanks Ori, your suggestions were very useful to discover the problem.

Comment: Glad I could help :)